# Swift : CollectionView ScollToItem is crashing in iOS version 12

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, crash, collectionview

We were struggling to fix the crash from 2 days but no luck, surprisingly other versions are working fine with the CollectionView ScrollToItem method where in iOS 12 crashing at the same line and showcase the reason invalid indexPath
but we do have a valid indexPath because I could see there is a number of images are loaded on collectionView. Hence confused about this case, was this a known problem in iOS 12, or do we have any fix for it
please help to close this issue, and thanks in advance

Giving below crash reason
**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x7f841e46feb0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}'**

Comment: The reason is quite obvious. You can debug the `indexPath` to see whether the numbers are correct. Also, please show your codes.

Comment: Debug the indexPath and also the number of row you setup before in the section of indexPath

Comment: Just put a check if your numberOfItemsInSection variable reaches the end index. 
Like this `if countVariable < indexPath.item {
 //do the work
 }`